# Combine two separate list of lists into one list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two lists of lists, for example below.

```
test1= [['A','B','C'],['G','H','I'],['M','N','O']]
test2= [['D','E','F'],['J','K','L'],['P','Q','R']]
```

I want to combine these two lists into another list of lists using each ones same index. Like so...

```
desired_result =  [['A','B','C','D','E','F'],['G','H','I','J','K','L'], 
['M','N','O','P','Q','R']]
```

The closest I have come to this so far is with this...

```
list3 = [list(a) for a in zip(test1, test2)]
list3
[[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']], [['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]]
```

Close, but not quite.  What am I missing here?  If there is a much easier way, I am obviously willing to do that also! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `[a+b for a,b in zip(test1, test2)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
list3 = [i[0]+i[1] for i in zip(test1,test2)]
>>> list3
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R']]
```